# Is Raspbian big-endian or little endian

Tags: raspbian, xorg

I'm getting a crashing bug in an X-Windows XCreateImage call. I could be wrong but it appears that Raspbian is running the pi 2 in big-endian mode. Can someone confirm/deny this suspicion?

Comment: Here you can find if its big endian or litle endian: http://serverfault.com/questions/163487/linux-how-to-tell-if-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian

Comment: I can deny that suspicion.

Answer (score 16):

lscpu shows that it is little endian.